Image optimisation when it comes to cropping and fetching the images without comprising on the quality
I have built an app that asks the users to pick multiple images (min 21) and then I display it all in a screen using a list view builder..
To tackle the memory overflow problem I used a cache width parameter. The problem with this is that the quality of the image is very bad when I am using a cache width param. Is there any other way I can solve this issue.
I tried the cache width parameter

Add code what you have done??
